# react-native section list data formate Question?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

How can I show the below array of objects in section list in react-native

```js
"RequiredPictures":{
    "Additional product ":[
        {
           "required_picture_id":"001",
           "label":"MRI",
           "has_picture":true,
            "url":"https:bbymakeitright.png"
        },
        {
           "required_picture_id":"002,
           "label":"MR",
           "has_picture":true,
            "url":"https:bbymakeitright.png"
        }
    ],
    "Additional product two":[
        {
           "required_picture_id":"003",
           "label":"IMR",
           "has_picture":true,
           "url":"https:bbymakeitright.png"
        },
        {
           "required_picture_id":"004",
           "label":"IR",
           "has_picture":false,
           "url":""
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to show "Additional product" and 'Additional product two" as the title of section and label in the object as the content item. How can I do so? Should I convert to any other formate to show it in the section list react-native?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to convert your data according to the format which supports by SectionList in React Native.

```
let RequiredPictures = {
    "Additional product": [
        {
            "required_picture_id": "001",
            "label": "MRI",
            "has_picture": true,
            "url": "https:bbymakeitright.png"
        },
        {
            "required_picture_id": "002",
            "label": "MR",
            "has_picture": true,
            "url": "https:bbymakeitright.png"
        }
    ],
    "Additional product two": [
        {
            "required_picture_id": "003",
            "label": "IMR",
            "has_picture": true,
            "url": "https:bbymakeitright.png"
        },
        {
            "required_picture_id": "004",
            "label": "IR",
            "has_picture": false,
            "url": ""
        }
    ]
}

let newData = [
    { title: Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[0], data: RequiredPictures[Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[0]] },
    { title: Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[1], data: RequiredPictures[Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[1]] },
]

console.log(newData)
```

Then you can use that data to display your Sectionlist

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SectionList, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const RequiredPictures = {
    "Additional product": [
        {
            "required_picture_id": "001",
            "label": "MRI",
            "has_picture": true,
            "url": "https:bbymakeitright.png"
        },
        {
            "required_picture_id": "002",
            "label": "MR",
            "has_picture": true,
            "url": "https:bbymakeitright.png"
        }
    ],
    "Additional product two": [
        {
            "required_picture_id": "003",
            "label": "IMR",
            "has_picture": true,
            "url": "https:bbymakeitright.png"
        },
        {
            "required_picture_id": "004",
            "label": "IR",
            "has_picture": false,
            "url": ""
        }
    ]
}

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        let newData = [
            { title: Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[0], data: RequiredPictures[Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[0]] },
            { title: Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[1], data: RequiredPictures[Object.keys(RequiredPictures)[1]] },
        ]
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
                <SectionList
                    sections={newData}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>{section.title}</Text>
                    )}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.label}</Text>}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score -1):

Try below

```
const sections = [
  {
    title: "Additional product",
    data: [
      {
         "required_picture_id":"001",
         "label":"MRI",
         "has_picture":true,
          "url":"https:bbymakeitright.png"
      },
      {
         "required_picture_id":"002,
         "label":"MR",
         "has_picture":true,
          "url":"https:bbymakeitright.png"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Additional product two",
    data: [
      {
         "required_picture_id":"003",
         "label":"IMR",
         "has_picture":true,
         "url":"https:bbymakeitright.png"
      },
      {
         "required_picture_id":"004",
         "label":"IR",
         "has_picture":false,
         "url":""
      }
    ]
  }
];

<SectionList sections={sections} />
```

Comment: I am getting API response as shown in above formate How can we do?.

Comment: If you know how to use `state`, just set data to state variable then you are good to go.

Comment: how can I change the formate of above-shown data to section list formate.

Comment: That is the format that is used in SectionList. Refer: https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#example